# Does reshaping a tensor retain the characteristics of original tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, reshape, tensor

I have a tensor T of the shape `(8, 5, 300)`, where 8 is the batch size, 5 is the number of documents in each batch, and 300 is the encoding of each of the document. If I reshape the Tensor as follows, does the properties of my Tensor remain the same?

```
T = T.reshape(5, 300, 8)
T.shape
>> Size[5, 300, 8]
```

So, does this new Tensor indicate the same properties as the original one? By the properties, I mean, can I say that this is also a Tensor of batch size 8, with 5 documents for each batch, and a 300 dimensional encoding for each document?

Does this affect the training of the model? If reshaping of Tensor messes up the datapoints, then there is no point in training. For example, If reshaping like above gives output as a batch of 5 samples, with 300 documents of size 8 each. If it happens so, then it's useless, since I do not have 300 documents, neither do I have batch of 5 samples.

I need to reshape it like this because my model in between produces output of the shape `[8, 5, 300]`, and the next layer accepts input as `[5, 300, 8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**

You need to understand the difference between [`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.reshape)/[`view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) and [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute).

`reshape` and `view` only changes the "`shape`" of the tensor, *without* re-ordering the elements. Therefore

```py
orig = torch.rand((8, 5, 300))
resh = orig.reshape(5, 300, 8)

orig[0, 0, :] != resh[0, :, 0]
```

If you want to change the order of the elements as well, you need to `permute` it:

```
perm = orig.permute(1, 2, 0)
orig[0, 0, :] == perm[0, :, 0]
```

Comment: So if I want my modified tensor to represent a batch of 8 samples, with 5 documents, each of which representing 300 dimensional docs, I need to permute it instead of reshaping it right?

Comment: @MikePatel exactly

Comment: Does it only affect the parameters of the layer in which I reshaped the tensor, or the whole model? The thing is I reshaped it before feeding it to particular layer, then from the output, I changed it back to original shape.

Answer (score 2):

NOOO!
I made a similar mistake.
Imagine you converting 2-d Tensor( Matrix) into 1-D Tensor(Array) and applying transform functionality on it. This would create serious issues in code as your new tensor has characteristic of an array.
Hope you got my point.

Comment: I asked this question after I started training, and now, I just checked if I got any answer. And sadly, I'll have to train my model again :(